# Unexpected Connections when trying to connect PowerBI to mySQL

Tags: mysql, microsoft-powerbi

When we open Power BI on the desktop client (PBIX file). It will automatically create a connection to the tables that are referenced in the file for some reason. Does anyone know why the connections start automatically issuing SELECT commands even if it has not been instructed to yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like the default data preview feature. It tries to load sample data (e.g. first 1,000 rows) for all your Queries.

You can turn that feature off from the menu: **File / Options and settings / Options / CURRENT FILE / Data Load / Background data**: uncheck **Allow data preview to download in the background**.

Note that setting is per PBIX file.